# Incompatible types of Request in Symfony tests

Tags: php, symfony

I have legacy code which use overrided Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request as CoreRequest;

class Request extends CoreRequest
{
```

So controllers look like

```
public function myAction(OverridedRequest $request)
{
```

I want to write some simple tests for these controllers, but I'm received errors about incompatible types.

> 1) Tests\AppBundle\Controller\ResidentControllerTest::testGetResidents
>
> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   AppBundle\Controller\ResidentController::getResidentsAction() must be
>   an instance of AppBundle\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, instance of
>   Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request given

How I can fix test for correct work?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have to create custom `app_test.php` front controller which you would use for testing purposes:

```
cp web/app_dev.php web/app_test.php
```

There instead of:

```
// ...
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
// ...
```

Instruct Symfony to use your custom Request:

```
// ...
$request = \AppBundle\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
// ...
```

Remember to change the environment name from `dev` to `test` as well :)